# Rails Jquery doesn't work on other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I believe jQuery doesn't work on other pages than the one you just installed. For example, when I type localhost:3000/, in the '/' directory all jQuery works. But when I click to a link created by Rails as

```
<%= link_to "Example Link", news_path %>
```

The page correctly loads, but the jQuery doesn't work. My jQuery codes are as stated:

```
$(function() {
  console.log( "pageloaded" );
  ....
  $('.up').click(function(){
    .....
  });
});
```

Comment: right click on your browser > inspect element > console .. post here error message.

Comment: There isn't any error message. But the jQuery doesn't get loaded.

Comment: what version of Rails are you using? In Rails 4, `turbolinks` is active by default and that means, that the new page is loaded dynamically and no $(document).ready is triggered. What happens if you manually load localhost:3000/news

Comment: In this case, how can I make a jquery function available for every page?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Rails 4 `turbolinks` is active by default.
That means, that `$(document).ready()` is not executed, when you load a new page.

`turbolink` fires a new event `page:load`. You can use this to run your javascript code:

```
$(document).on('page:load', your_start_function);
```

There is an excelent [rails cast on turbolinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks)

Comment: +1 and if you want to turn turbo links off :) - http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

Comment: Actually, there is gem called "jquery.turbolinks" that binds page:load event with jquery ready event

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

This gem binds jQuery.ready function with Turbolinks listen event page:load, therefore the solution is supposed to be solved if you are using Turbolinks with Rails 4

Answer (score 0):

You need `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile (then bundle install if you're using bundler)

Once that's done, you need to require it in your `application.js` file:

```
//= require jquery
```

Last, you need to ensure that the `application.js` file is loaded as part of the application template. In `application.html.erb` you should have the following:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

I believe that this is all there by default in a Rails install so if you have removed any of these settings you'll need to add them back to get it to work.

Comment: jquery rails gem is installed correctly, and jquery functions well on the first page.