# Rails 4 TurboLinks and jQuery Dynamic Links Not Playing Nice

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am developing an application in Rails 4.0 and I'm having an issue with turbolinks not playing nice with some jQuery code I have.  I have  a Quote model that has a related QuoteItems model.  I am using accepts_nested_attributes_for and some jQuery to populate the line items form.

When I click on a link bringing me to the new_quote_path,  The dynamic link doesn't fire the javascript code.  When I refresh the page,  the form WORKS GREAT.  I like turbolinks as it is super fast, but not sure how to get this to work in development.  Here's some code.

in quotes.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_line_items', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()

$('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Quotes view new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @quote, :class => "hello" do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :quote_date, "Date of Quote" %>  <br/>
        <%= f.text_field :quote_date %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :good_through %> <br/>
        <%= f.text_field :good_through %>
      </p>

      <p>
        <%= f.label :quote_number %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :quote_number %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= f.label :customer_id, "Customer" %><br/>
        <%= select(:quote, :customer_id, Customer.all.collect {|c| [ c.fname, c.id ] }, :prompt => "Select Customer") %>
      </p>

      <%= f.fields_for :quote_items do |builder| %>
          <%= render 'quote_item_fields', :f => builder %>
      <% end %>

      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Line Item", f, :quote_items %>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit %>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was having the same problem, if you want to keep turbolinks working and your dynamic jquery on, try this gem: [jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

Hope it helps

Comment: @WiliantoIndrawan I can try: if you have bindings on your domain, Turbolinks will affect them: It's because the nodes on which you bind events no longer exist as turbolinks remove and replace. See the gem decription, it explains it quite well

Answer (score 9):

Some options:

1) turn off turbolinks - see http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4

2) use new `page:load` event that turbolinks fires - `$(document).on('page:load', your_start_function);`, see [Rails Jquery doesn't work on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381069/rails-jquery-doesnt-work-on-other-pages?answertab=active#tab-top) - guessing in your case it would be something like

```
$(document).on 'page:load' ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_line_items', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: You should probably use `$(document).on 'ready page:load', ->` to ensure that the ready function is called on both hard refreshes and turbolink pages.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it will help:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('#some_element_id').click ->
     alert "Clicked!"
```

Comment: Tried a lot of things (all above) and this finally worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Turbo links uses AJAX which means any dynamically generated elements never get their ready events assigned (because the page isn't technically loading after the first load).  Instead, you need to listen to the top DOM element `body` or `document` and then specify a selector for the dynamic element to listen to:

`$('body').on('click', '.remove_line_items', function(e) { ... });`

([More](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=asciicast) [Details](http://www.iexposure.com/2012/10/26/rails-4-turbolinks-and-delegated-event-handling-in-jquery))