# Rails 4 : JS doesn't work when I follow links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, assets

I use rails 4. The problem that I have is when I follow the links in my rails app - some js libraries doesnt't work(jquery.inview.js , ckeditor/init). When I refresh page - everything works just fine.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require jquery.inview.min.js
//= require jquery.inview.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require_tree .
```

When I remove turbolinks from application.js - everything works well

Comment: jQuery and turbolinks don't play nice together.  See this thread for some possible solutions.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386740/rails-4-turbolinks-and-jquery-dynamic-links-not-playing-nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem myself with links working only on refresh in my Rails 4 app and one of the solutions discussed in the this link worked for me:

http://srbiv.github.io/2013/04/06/rails-4-my-first-run-in-with-turbolinks.html

Not sure if this will work for you but TurboLinks is used by Rails 4 by default and it is worth reviewing how it works as it can have unintended side effects if not set up or used correctly.

Comment: Please do me the favor of accepting my solution so my StackExchange reputation improves. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed understanding turbolinks is a bit trickier. @user2686755 please accept this answer, as it leeds to the right direction.

Comment: This helped me, too, though I had to use page:fetch rather than page:load (see above-linked page.)

Answer (score 0):

I can only speculate here, but I would presume that if you are doing a single-page app, or replacing a portion of content with new content, that your events are still pointing to the old content on initial page load, instead of detecting the partial change, and re-binding to those elements.

Comment: No, it's not a single-page app and I don't think that it's the case. Because when I remove turbolinks from application.js - everything start working as it is supposed to work