# How to show an associated value from a selected record in Rails 4.0 form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am fairly new to RoR, currently working on a little free app for amateur sports clubs managers that help them to keep track of payments. This app shows relevant player data and a form to collect fees (tarifa) payments. I want to show the fee for the concept being paid before the payment is entered. This is the app view with the form and the HTML generated: [form for pagos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maFbL.png)

this is the pagos_controller.rb 'new' action:

```
def new
  @pago = Pago.new
  @conceptos = Concepto.all
  @jugador = Jugador.find_by(id: params[:jugador_id])
end
```

and this is the views/pagos/_form.html.erb rendered into the views/pagos/new.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for(@pago) do |f| %>
 <% if @pago.errors.any? %>
  <p> All the error showing logic is omitted here for simplicity </p>
 <div class="field-tm">
   <%= f.label :concepto %>
   <%= f.collection_select :concepto, @conceptos, :name, :name %>
 </div>
 <div class="field-tm">
   <%= f.label :tarifa %> <div id="la-tarifa"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="field-tm">
   <%= f.text_field :cantidad, :placeholder => "Cantidad a pagar" %>
 </div>
 <%= f.hidden_field :jugador_id, :value => params[:jugador_id] %>
 <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Registrar Pago", class: "btn btn-default"%>
 </div>
<% end %>
```

This is the pagos schema...

```
create_table "pagos", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "concepto"
  t.decimal  "cantidad"
  t.integer  "jugador_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

And the Conceptos schema:

```
create_table "conceptos", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.decimal  "tarifa"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

I need to get the value selected in the 'collection_select' to use it to find that concept's tarifa like in

```
@conceptos.find_by(name: theConceptoName).tarifa
```

and put it in the

```
$("#la-tarifa").text(tarifa)
```

to show the value, but don't know how to get a 'theConceptoName'  variable that works from the

```
<%= f.collection_select :concepto, @conceptos, :name, :name %>
```

I've tried several ways and I came up with jQuery way to get the value, so it would be something like this:

```
$("#pago_concepto").change( function(){
  var miConcepto = $("#pago_concepto").value();
  do the @conceptos search for miConcepto and get the tarifa;(*)
  $("#la-tarifa").text(tarifa);
});
```

but then how do I do the query(*) within the pagos.cofee code to get the tarifa value from @conceptos... I have done a lot of google research but every answer I find confuses me more.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just a simple ajax find:

JS:

```
$("#pago_concepto").change( function(){
  var miConcepto = $("#pago_concepto").value();
  $.getJSON('/tarifa/' + miConcepto, function(data) {
    $("#la-tarifa").text(data.tarifa);
  });
});
```

pagos_controller:

```
def tarifa
  tarifa = Concepto.find_by(name: params[:concept_name]).tarifa
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {tarifa: tarifa} }
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
get '/tarifa/:concept_name', to: 'pagos#tarifa'
```

Should be relatively easy to convert js to coffeescript if you want to.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not able to get the 'tarifa' value, I may be doing something wrong. If I inspect the jQuery in the browser I can get a valid response for $("#pago_concepto).val() but $("#la-tarifa").val is still "". Any further ideas?

Comment: it should be `$("#pago_concepto).val()`. Are you saying you not getting the value when you select an item from down?

Comment: Yes, I did catch the difference with .val(), so I did correct it in the first time. I disabled Turbolinks and now it is working fine, yet I don't know if this is going to affect any part of the system, currently it is working ok. I would like to have your comments and by the way, thanks for your help, very enlightening.

Comment: `Started GET "/tarifa/Temporada" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-28 12:36:32 -0500<br>     Processing by PagosController#tarifa as JSON<br>
        Parameters: {"concept_name"=>"Temporada"}<br>
    Temporada<br>
        Concepto Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "conceptos".* FROM "conceptos" WHERE "conceptos"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "Temporada"]]<br>
    Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)`

Comment: I think turbolink can mess up existing jquery events but I'm not sure as I don't use turbolink often. Try to install `jquery-turbolinks` gem as this SO recommended  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386740/rails-4-turbolinks-and-jquery-dynamic-links-not-playing-nice) and see if it plays nicely with turbolinks. Will appreciate an accepted answer if my solution help you :)