# JavaScript code not loaded (only the first time)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

When accessing the below url for the first time, most of javascript code is not loaded :

http://goo.gl/PxsVhZ

*(images below the " WHY CHOOSE US ?" are not animated)*

But if you refresh the page, javascript will be loaded and acts normally.

Project was created with **RoR** and deploy with **capistrano** (with asset compilation). Apache is used as proxy and send data to the web server (unicorn).

The site is still under development (english translation too...), thanks for your understanding.

EDIT : If animation appears during your first access, click on the "home" → "home" and then "home" →　"why choose us".. javascript should be broken.

If someone has any idea, I would be glad to hear it ! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont put your Javascript in footer. It should be in a file like `app/assets/javascripts/myfile.js`  Then include this file in application.js with `//= require myfile` . Reason - when we navigate from one page to another, common templates like header and footer do not load again only the body changes (you can observe that visually). So, javascript in footer stays there and is visible in HTML source code but does not gets executed with second page load.

P.S. There are a few solutions http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4 or github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks , To understand the problem and solutions [Rails Jquery doesn't work on other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381069/rails-jquery-doesnt-work-on-other-pages)

Comment: Thank you. As you can see, I have no JavaScript code in my footer (only for google analytics). I've put my JavaScript code contains in <head> in a JavaScript file under asset....but the same error occurs.

Comment: bxslider code is in <head> as separate <script></script>. Its not the way as explained in the answer above.

Comment: I've changed code in my development environment (not in production). I cannot access my production server now, but I will deploy the new version in few hours.. thank your for your patience

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have deployed the new version (with javascript code loaded in a asset/javascript file), but problem persists. Can you check please ?

Comment: There are a few solutions http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4 or https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks , To understand the problem and solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381069/rails-jquery-doesnt-work-on-other-pages

Comment: I've added the jquery.turbolinks and now it works... thank you