# Rails 4 jquery function works once, not on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Working in Rails 4.2.5, I have the following code in my
`application.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#property_selection #properties").click(function() {
    var url = window.location.href
            .replace(/\/?$|(\?|&)current_prop_id=[^?&]+/g, "")
        + "?current_prop_id="
            + $("#properties option:selected").val();
    window.location.href = url;
    })
});
```

I.e., when I select a property_id, I want to go to the same URL, plus
`"?current\_prop\_id="`, plus the ID.

This works the first time I login. When I visit a path like
`http://localhost:3000/foo`, however, it doesn't. Hitting refresh on
the page makes it work again.

Then I changed the `$(document).ready` line to
`$(document).on('page:load', ...`, (based on what I'd read
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381069/rails-jquery-doesnt-work-on-other-pages?rq=1)),
but that only reversed the problem. Now it works the first time, but
not the second.

Dropping this code into a static file works just fine.

I now have both defined in `application.js`, which feels wrong on
many levels, but I don't know what to do to get the function to work in
both cases otherwise. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like (coffee script syntax):

```
$ ->
    do_on_load()
    $(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load)
```

or javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  do_on_load();
  $(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load);
}
```

where do_on_load() is the function with the instructions that should be executed. Anyway, this is caused by turbolinks + jquery and it's really annoying. Change the order they're being loaded in your application.js also influence on that behavior. I suggest reconsider using turbolinks... it will give you some headaches. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I did reconsider turbolinks, or rather, considered it for the first time and removed all references to it in my code. I don't remember putting any reference to it in any of my files, so a generator must have done it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when i had before with jquery function to load my images. The reason for this how Turbolinks load pages. Some nodes you bind with your page doesnt exist anymore.

I used `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to resolve my problems. check the gem [here](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) try it out if it solves your problem. good luck mate.

Comment: Thanks for the turbolinks tip. I opted to remove it from my config, though, as the gem `jquery-turbolinks` didn't appear to help. I'm not even sure where the references for them came from, unless a generator automatically created them. Thanks again.